# Привязка кнопки

Tags: .net, c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {}
```

Как привязать кнопку на нажатие F1 или другие.

У меня есть SWF. Как сделать, чтобы SWF запускалась на 2-5 сек, играла и программа запускалась.

Answer (score 1):

У формы нужно установить свойство **KeyPreview** в **true**, если оно установлено в **true**, то в начале все события клавиатуры будут проходить через обработчики формы, а уж потом через обработчики компонентов на форме.

Затем у формы есть событие **KeyDown** в нем нужно описать следующее:

```
 private: System::Void Form1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) 
  {
      if (Convert::ToString(e->KeyCode)=="F1")    // Если была нажата клавиша F1
      {
         // Здесь вызвать обработчик события нажатия нужной вам кнопки; 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Может не самое рациональное решение, но все же!